# Observable DataBinding ObservableInt vs. LiveData with different results On Confguration change

Tags: java, android, observable, android-databinding, android-livedata

I am testing the behavior of `DataBinding` observable when it comes to use a `LiveData` vs. `ObservableInt`.

I have simple layout with a button that triggers a counter for both `LiveData` & `ObservableInt` variables that I store in the `ViewModel`, I update their values using `BindingAdapter`

Both  `LiveData` & `ObservableInt` variables count up normally; but when there is a device configuration change (screen rotation for my test), the `ObservableInt` countinues count up with button hits, although the `LiveData` dismisses one or two counts.

Below gif will illustrate more

[image]

My question is how to solve this problem? 
I mainly need a `LiveData` for further `Transformations`

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.android.databindingobservableintlivedata.MyViewModel" />

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/observableint_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ObservableInt: " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/observableint_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                app:textValueForObservableInt="@{viewmodel.countObservableInt}" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/livedata_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LiveData: " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/livedata_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                app:textValueForLiveData="@{viewmodel.countLiveData}" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewmodel.onCount()}"
            android:text="Count" />


    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityMainBinding mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        MyViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

        mBinding.setViewmodel(viewModel);
        mBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this); 

    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> countLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>(0);
    public ObservableInt countObservableInt = new ObservableInt(0);

    public void onCount() {
        countObservableInt.set(countObservableInt.get() + 1);
        int value = countLiveData.getValue() == null ? 0 : countLiveData.getValue();
        countLiveData.postValue(value + 1);
    }

}
```

**BindingAdapters**

```
public class BindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter("textValueForObservableInt")
    public static void bindObservableIntInText(TextView text, ObservableInt value) {
        text.setText(String.valueOf(value.get()));
    }

    @BindingAdapter("textValueForLiveData")
    public static void bindLiveDataIntegerInText(TextView text, MutableLiveData<Integer> value) {
        text.setText(String.valueOf(value.getValue()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Inspite of `countLiveData.postValue(value + 1)`, use `countLiveData.setValue(value + 1)` as you're already on main thread.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `postValue` and `setValue`?

Comment: yes, thank you for notifying this, actually that seems the real issue of the dismissed counts, I am testing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Post value](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData.html#postValue(T)) of `LiveData`:

Basically this method indicates that, any value given to `LiveData` can be/should be called from background thread *(other than main thread)* would reflect on main thread with updated value.

Meaning that, if you've got two consecutive calls to `LiveData` about `postValue()` then only last value would be dispatched!

In your case, `countLiveData.postValue(value + 1)` this line gets impacted on **post-increment of value** if there're too frequent calls to this method, which in case only gets updated for last value but not on consecutive ones.

[Set Value](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData.html#setValue(T)) of `LiveData`:

This method requires that call must be made from Main thread, resulting UI gets reflected/updated every time no matter how many calls you've made. None of intermediate calls get discarded.

### TL;DR

If you've to update/set value from background thread then use `postValue()` method otherwise use `setValue()` when on Main thread.

---

> It takes a while for device rotation when I have continuous hits on the button, and suddenly rotate the device.

Reason is that when you call `setValue()` on main thread before rotating device, each calls must update the UI consecutively, resulting delay on rotation stuff *(Holds the UI updates before configuration change happen)*. That's why it lags/delay on rotation before all `setValue()` call completes UI updates *(this line in your particular case: `app:textValueForLiveData="@{viewmodel.countLiveData}"`)*.